# Getting role name from user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

In a WebAPI project, i want to return the role name, that a users is a member of (they can only be in 1 role at a time).

I currently have this:

```
var users = UserManager.Users.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, Email = u.Email, Role = u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId });
```

obviously, this only return the id of the role. How can i get the role name, in a one-liner-type?

Comment: `Roles.Find(r => r.Id == RoleId).Name` ...?

Comment: .. 'iCollection does not contain a defination for Find..' (Role = u.Roles.Find(r => r.Id == RoleId).Name)

Comment: If you have 'id of  the role' , simply     RoleManager.FindById(yourRoleId) should work

Comment: @sepehr no luck :(

Comment: @brother , do you use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager` ? what about `asp.net identity`? :) with smile things getting better

Comment: I tried with this: var users = UserManager.Users.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, Email = u.Email, Role = RoleManager.FindById(u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId).Name });. But this return 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole FindById..'

Answer (score 0):

You may try with (assuming that your `Role` class have a `Name` field):

```
var users = UserManager.Users.Select(
        u => new { Id = u.Id, 
                    Email = u.Email, 
                    Role = u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Name 
                    });
```

Comment: 'IdentutyUserRole does not contain a defnition for Name'. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Role` is `enum` you can use this, to get name of enum

```
var users = UserManager.Users.Select(u => 
    new { 
        Id = u.Id, 
        Email = u.Email, 
        Role = Enum.GetName(typeof(Role),u.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId) });
```

Comment: I get a 'Role does not excist in the current context'?

Comment: Did you check spelling? Is `Role` a class or an enum?